# Qt5 OpenFileDialog behaves strange on Gnome3

Tags: c++, qt, gnome, qt5, gnome-3

I am trying to get a file path at my Qt project. When I was using KDE4 and Qt 4.8 everything worked fine but now I updated to Qt 5 and Gnome 3. And the `QFileDialog` now looks like this:

[image]

Or even like this:

[image]

But more often it looks like this:

[image]

I noticed the behaviour changes depending on the path being passed as the initial path for the dialog. E. g., if I call

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(this->parent()), tr("Choose model"), QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), QLatin1String("*.obj"));
```

then I get the second case screenshot.

Yet, if I call

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(this->parent()), tr("Choose model"), QString(), QLatin1String("*.obj"));
```

then I get any folder empty while it is not (the first case screenshot).

Also, using [this hint](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=999078#p999078), I managed that commenting one line at my `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file and changing the theme to `ambiance` instead of `adwaita` at `gnome-tweak-tool` makes my application show the second-case screenshot.

I use this code to show up the dialog:

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(this->parent()), tr("Choose model"), QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), QLatin1String("*.obj"));
```

Here, `this` points to the `QGraphicsScene` ancestor, `OpenGLScene`. Here is the code where I create one:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    GraphicsView view;
    view.setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
    view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
    view.setScene(new OpenGLScene);
    view.show();

    view.resize(1024, 768);

    return app.exec();
}
```